# Retrieving field dynamically from anonymous object

Tags: apex, custom-object, object, dynamic-apex, inheritance

I have a scenario where I need to dynamically retrieve fields from a custom object, in which I don't know the `type`. *For the following code, the query is passed in from somewhere else, I just wrote it out for the purposes of this example.*

This code works, however, the type is obviously explicit:

```
House__c o = Database.query('Select Id, NumberOfRooms__c from House__c limit 1');
System.debug(o.get('NumberOfRooms__c'));
```

So I thought I could write this code:

```
Object o = Database.query('Select Id, NumberOfRooms__c from House__c limit 1');
System.debug(o.get('NumberOfRooms__c'));
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String)
> from the type Object

It looks like the `.get()` method isn't available on `object`, but is available on custom objects. Is this inherited from a class higher up in the hierarchy? If so, what can I cast `o` to to get this method?

Or, alternatively, is there another way to dynamically retrieve the value of fields on the `object` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Object` to `SObject`

```
SObject o = Database.query('Select Id, NumberOfRooms__c from House__c limit 1');
System.debug(o.get('NumberOfRooms__c'));
```

---

`SObject` class has [get](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) method to dynamically get field value.

Any standard/custom object extends `SObject` and `SObject` extends `Object`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.